# How to stop Internet Explorer caching AJAX pages

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I'm not using JQuery or any other library. I simply have a PHP file which spits out a JSON result and my javascript acts accordingly.

Unfortunatly, I've just spent an hour banging my head against a wall trying to figure out why I'm getting an 'undefined' for one of my variables where I *KNOW* I've set it in my php output.

I finally figured it out: I went straight to the php page in IE and found that it had a cached result (i.e., before I added that variable to the JSON string). As soon as I hit refresh, it got the new page and my code all suddenly started working.

How can I force IE (and other browsers) not to cache my AJAX pages, since they're likely going to change very frequently anyway?

Comment: jQuery has solved this by adding a dynamic parameter to the URL. E.g. `mysite.com/page.php?parm1=val1&parm2=val2&_nocache=213324933`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Add a timestamp or something random to your request

or

> Use POST instead of GET

Comment: the http verb (POST or GET) should be related to the intent of your request. For instance, if the request is getting info with no intended side effect, it should us GET. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html. However, json arrays should be retreived with POST for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to append a timestamp to the URL in question, eg

```
var url += url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&";
url += "_=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks! I've appended `"&_=" + new Date().getTime()` to all my AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2):

Set the expiraton header proprerly to the response or add a random or timestamp fake parameter to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Append the url with either Time, as suggested by others or use following:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);

url = page.php?v=var&r=rand;
```